# Open Sharepoint link in a external Tab

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2013 Document Library with URL's in the library. I was wondering is there a way for me to specify a particular URL that I wanted to open in an external tab with JavaScript, I know I can do something like this

```
$("a[href$='.aspx']").removeAttr('onclick').attr("target","_blank");
```

But I have other ASPX pages that I don't want opened in an external tab. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using calculated columns. You will need the column for your url, a yes/no column to define if you want the url to open in a new tab or not, and the calculated column which will be the clickable url.

The calculated column formula would look like this. Replace NewTab and UrlText with your appropriate column names. The extra parentheses around the CONCATENATE aren't really necessary I am just trying to help with readability.

```
    =IF(NewTab=TRUE,
(CONCATENATE("<a href=",UrlText," target=new>",UrlText,"</a>")),
(CONCATENATE("<a href=",UrlText,">",UrlText,"</a>")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can give them another attribute to detect if they should be opened in new tab or not(We will use `new-tab` as our attribute):
**html**:

```
<a href="http://somelink.com" new-tab="false">Click to go to some link!</a>
<a href="http://somelink.com" new-tab="true">Click to go to some link!</a>
```

**JS**:

```
$("a[href$='.aspx']").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).attr('new-tab') == "true"){
         window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
    }
});
```